# How do I write "all-in-one" correctly?

Tags: punctuation, capitalization

How do I write "all-in-one"? Should it have capital letters? Should it have hyphens?

I have done some googling, but I have not found a consistent result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes hyphens:

> **all-in-one:** adjective [ attrib. ]
>
> combining two or more items or functions in a single unit: *an all-in-one shampoo/conditioner.*

(from the *New Oxford American Dictionary*)

No capitalization is required, unless it's at the beginning of a sentence, of course.

Comment: Source? Cite references!